# Why is the total read number still more than the paired in sequencing after removing the duplicate in samtools flagstat output?

Tags: ngs, samtools

After alignment using BWA, I have removed the dupliment using the samtools(Version: 1.9).

My procedure is as follows:

```
bwa mem -k 32 -M ref.fa read1 read2 > out.sam 
samtools view -@ 0 -b -T ref.fa -o out.bam in.sam
samtools sort -n -o out.nameSrt.bam in.bam
samtools fixmate -r -m in.nameSrt.bam out.fixmate.bam
samtools sort -o out.fixmate.sort.bam in.fixmate.bam
samtools markdup -r -S -s in.fixmate.sort.bam out.markdup.bam
samtools flagstat in.markdup.bam > out.markdup.flagstat
```

The flagstat output result is as follows:

```
21611397 + 0 in total (QC-passed reads + QC-failed reads)
0 + 0 secondary
0 + 0 supplementary
0 + 0 duplicates
21611397 + 0 mapped (100.00% : N/A)
21422330 + 0 paired in sequencing
10711165 + 0 read1
10711165 + 0 read2
19797684 + 0 properly paired (92.42% : N/A)
21422330 + 0 with itself and mate mapped
0 + 0 singletons (0.00% : N/A)
1306000 + 0 with mate mapped to a different chr
727043 + 0 with mate mapped to a different chr (mapQ>=5)
```

Why is the total read number still more than the paired in sequencing after removing the duplicate in samtools flagstat output?
Is there anything wrong with my procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bwa-mem may produce chimeric alignment, where different parts of a read are mapped to distinct loci. flagstat counts them as two reads.